# Problema con Javascript 'document' is not defined

Tags: javascript, brackets

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AQUI esta el codigo

```
var nic = document.getElementsByClassName('formulario__input'); 
for(var i = 0; i< nic.length; i++) {
    nic[i].addEventListener('Keyup', function(){
        if(this.value.length>=1){
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('fijar');
        }else{
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('fijar');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: El editor me esta diciendo del error

Comment: prueba `keyup` en lugar de  `Keyup`

Comment: Prueba a poner tu código dentro de este bloque: **`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed"); //aquí tu código
  });`** [Ver aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) para más detalles. Todo código JS que maneje elementos del DOM debería verificar primero si el mismo ha sido cargado.

Comment: Como dice @enxaneta debes poner `keyup`. Así el listener funciona, pero no estoy seguro que luego puedas hacer uso de `this` para obtener el valor de algún elemento dentro de esa clase (un `input` por ejemplo), porque ahí `this` representaría al contenedor. Deberías dar más detalles sobre lo que hay en la clase `formulario__input` y lo que quieres hacer en realidad. Por ejemplo, ¿qué quieres escuchar en esa clase, los cambios en elementos input solamente o en otro tipo de elementos? Puede que aquí sea más conveniente el uso de `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Como dijo @enxaneta el problema era 'Keyup', ahora me funciona el código, gracias a todos por su ayuda c: